# Is it possible to host a MVC application using AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, model-view-controller

AWS S3 ask for index.html file, but MVC application contain cshtml file, so can we host MVC application in AWS S3? if it is possible please share how it is.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. AWS S3 is a cloud STORAGE service, it is not there for running code. You will need a service that contains processing capacity because MVC applications contain server running code.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

States: "Object storage built to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere"

You will have to go to Amazon AWS.